# Mount ftp as filesystem

Tags: ftp, mount

What is the most stable way of mounting an FTP filesystem? `curlftpfs` doesn't work very reliably for me :/  is there a better way?

**Edit:** I'm on ubuntu!

**Edit 2:** I tried version 0.9.2. I did a mount, and then a `cp ../index.html .` and I get `cp: closing './index.html': Input/output error`. (This is the third ftp-server I'm having trouble with, and I've reinstalled the system in between.)

If it's of any help, I do `curlftpfs -o user=xxx:yyy ftp.example.com ftpdir`

Comment: What OS are you using? What version of curlftpfs are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Which version of curlftpfs are you using? I hope it's not the unstable 0.9.2-1. Try a slightly older version. I don't know what OS you're using, but if it's OS X you could look at [WebDrive](http://www.webdrive.com/) or [ExpanDrive](http://www.expandrive.com/mac).

Comment: Ok, I'll try an earlier version. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @aioobe Try 0.9.2, not the 0.9.2-1 version

Comment: edited question :(

Comment: @aioobe Sorry, I'm out of ideas. =(

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo curlftpfs -o umask=0777,uid=1000,gid=1000,allow_other \
ftp://username:password@your.ftpserver.here /media/ftpmountedhere
```

Try that command

Answer (score 0):

use gnome nautilus then "open in terminal"

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/500346)

Comment: @bjoster seriously?

Comment: @bjoster technically speaking this is the correct answer, because this way the FTP server actually gets mounted via GVFS (built around FUSE)